# Does ApexCharts support Y-axis panning?

Tags: apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

Apex Charts whereby it cannot pan in the y-axis. The user can zoom in with both axes, but they can then only pan horizontally.

I just want to make sure if we can pan vertically in the ApexCharts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**No.** It seems that you cannot pan vertically with ApexCharts.

I found this "old" thread (2019) where the library author confirms that this feature is not supported: [Vertical panning · Issue #978 · apexcharts/apexcharts.js · GitHub](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/978)

We can only enable or disable panning in the toolbar with a boolean (see [toolbar – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/)). We have `chart.zoom` options (see [zoom – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/zoom/)), but there is no `chart.pan`.